# How to scroll using custom scrollbars in android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, scrollbar

I want to use custom ScrollBars in android WebView; and also want to use that scrollbar to scroll WebView content. I know that we can show scrollbars using:

```
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

But if I use thode default scrollbars, then I am not able to scroll the content of WebView by dragging scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to custom Scroll Bar of WebView. Just add this attribute code to xml of WebView with your custom:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/your_custom_scrollbar_thumb"
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/your_custom_scrollbar_track"
```

Comment: I want to scroll the content of WebView by dragging scrollbar. Is this possible using this?

Comment: I tried this it shows custom track and thumb but I cannot scroll the content of WebView by dragging scrollbar.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar you can't scroll content by scrollbar by default, you must implement a GestureDetector to handle scrolling in WebView